# Where can I find the algorithm in pseudocode for deleting a key from a B-Tree?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, b-tree

I am reading the chapter on B-Trees in Introduction to Algorithms (3rd edition) by Cormen and found the deletion procedure very confusing. I could understand the algorithm for insertion because it provided the pseudocode along with a few examples, like this:

[image: Algorithm to insert a key 'k' into a tree T]

[image: Algorithm for the sub-procedure Insert-Nonfull(x,k) in B-Tree-Insert]

But for deletion, it just says... "We sketch how deletion works instead of presenting the pseudocode" followed by steps which are very confusing. The very first step says:

> 1. If the key k is in node x and x is a leaf, delete the key k from x.

But if I delete a key from the leaf, won't it violate the B-tree property if the number of keys is less than the minimum required?

Answer (score 3):

According to Knuth's definition, a B-tree of order m is a tree which satisfies the following properties:

- Every node has at most m children.
- Every non-leaf node (except root) has at least ⌈m/2⌉ child nodes.
- The root has at least two children if it is not a leaf node.
- A non-leaf node with k children contains k − 1 keys.
- All leaves appear in the same level.

Let's look at following B-tree (order 5)

[image]

Lets look at various possible deletions.

**delete 21**

Not a problem.

- Every node still has at most 5 children.
- The node containing 21 is a leaf, so all the rules that mention 'non-leaf nodes' don't apply.
- All leaves still appear on the same level

**delete 16**

Needs to be rebalanced. The root now contains 1 element, which is 1 short of m/2 (rounded down).

In order to fix it, we borrow an element (for instance 18 or 21) and move it from that leaf to the root itself. If the tree were larger, we'd repeat this procedure recursively down.

**general remark**

Keep in mind that most implementations work with "marked as deleted" nodes, rather than actually deleting the nodes.
Marking a node as deleted is relatively easy compared to actually performing a delete and potentially rebalancing the tree.
Furthermore, deletion typically doesn't happen as often as insertion.

Comment: In delete 16, "Needs to be rebalanced". Why? It's the root node, so the 2nd property that says "except root" doesn't apply to it, right? Also, it still has at least 2 children so property 3 is also satisfied. Why can't I just merge [18,21] into [9,12] and then remove 16 and its right pointer completely?

Comment: Thanks for the general remark, makes it seem there is no ONE correct algorithm to do deletion. After some thinking, I can see that my approach will fail if the bottom nodes are not leaf nodes. Can you algorithm-ise your answer? Is it right to say that your algorithm is: delete it; borrow predecessor/successor from left/right child; if borrowing from that node makes it unbalanced, recursively do the above procedure? Does this algorithm cover all possible cases?

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to work this thing out. I will use these cases stated in the book, but modify the statements a little bit so they look clearer:

1. Case 1: If the node of k is an internal node, but not a leaf. This
   corresponds to the original description case 2.

   - Case 1a: if y has at least t keys, and
   - Case 1b: y has fewer than t keys but z has at least t keys.
   - Case 1c: both y and z have only t - 1 keys.
2. Case 2: if this BTree only has a root left, and want to delete a key from the root. Note that the original descriptions missed this case. Although at that stage the root does become a leaf (then go to case 3) but you need to first set it as a leaf node at all when the very last 3 nodes have been merged to become one leaf node (and from deletion perspective you can only reach one leaf node only through this way).
3. Case 3: If the node is a leaf, and removing a key does not
   cause the node having too few keys. This corresponds to the original
   description case 1.
4. Case 4: If the node is a leaf, but the removal
   of k from the node leads to either the node itself having too few
   keys or its parent having too few keys. This corresponds to the
   original description case 3.

   - Case 4a: Both siblings have the number of keys either 0 or t-1. This corresponds to origin description case 3b. Then we need to merge the siblings with a key up level (from the parent). As this may result in parent node having keys less than t-1 because the number of keys in the parent is now decreased by 1 due to this merging, you need to merge parents and recursively check its ancestors till root, if necessary.
   - Case 4b: One of the siblings of the node to be deleted has more than t-1 keys, such that we can "grab" a key from its parent, and let the parent "grab" another from its sibling. This corresponds to origin description case 3a. Note that in this particular situation the number of keys in the parent is not affected, only what keys it has changed due to this grabbing process.

I can not think of any cases other than these.

To make this deletion code clearer and easier to come up with, these are the subroutines I wrote.

```
    def search(self, k, node=None, pth=[], level=0): 
        """Give a key to search, return the node (as the page in computer 
        system concepts), path to this node (which nodes were went through), 
        idx of the key in the node found, and level in this BTree 
        of this node."""
        node = node or self.root
        idx = bisect.bisect_left(node.keys, k)

        if idx < len(node.keys) and k == node.keys[idx]:
            return (node, pth, idx, level)
        elif node.isLeaf:
            if k in node.keys:
                return (node, pth, idx, level)            
            raise KeyError("Key not found in this BTree!")
        else:
            pth.append(node)
            return self.search(k, node.pointers[idx], pth, level + 1)
    
    def getSiblings(self, node, parent, i=None):
        if i == None:
            i = bisect.bisect_left(parent.keys, node.keys[0])
        leftSibling, rightSibling = None, None
        
        try:
            if i > 0: leftSibling = parent.pointers[i - 1]
        except IndexError: 
            pass
        
        try:
            rightSibling = parent.pointers[i + 1]
        except IndexError: 
            pass
        
        return (leftSibling, rightSibling)
    
    def __mergeWithSibling(self, node, leftSibling, rightSibling, pth, i):
        if leftSibling != None: 
            self.__mergeNodes(leftSibling, node, pth[-1], i - 1, i)
        else:
            self.__mergeNodes(node, rightSibling, pth[-1], i)
        
    def __mergeNodes(self, node, nodeToMerge, parent, i, ptr=None):
        if ptr == None: ptr = i + 1
        node.keys += parent.keys[i]
        node.keys += nodeToMerge.keys
        node.pointers += nodeToMerge.pointers
        
        del parent.keys[i]
        del parent.pointers[ptr]

        
    def __checkAndMerge(self, node, pth=None):
        """Check if a given node should be merged with its sibling."""
        if pth == None:
            pth = self.search(node[0])[1]
        
        if len(node.keys) < self.t - 1:
            i = bisect.bisect_left(pth[-1].keys, node.keys[0])
            leftSibling, rightSibling = self.getSiblings(node, pth[-1], I)
            self.__mergeWithSibling(node, leftSibling, rightSibling, pth, I)
            self.__checkAndMerge(pth[-1], pth[:-1])
```

And below is the code (very easy to be changed to pseudocode you might want):

```
def deleteKey(self, k):
    node, pth, idx, level = self.search(k)
    
    if not node.isLeaf:
        # Case 1: If node of k is an internal node, but not leaf:
        i = bisect.bisect_left(node.keys, k)
        y = node.pointers[i] # y is the child that precedes k.     
        
        if len(y.keys) >= self.t:
            # Case 1a, if y has at least t keys
            print("Running case 2a")
            pred = y.keys[-1]
            self.deleteKey(pred)
            node.keys[i] = pred
        else:            
            # Case 1b: y has fewer than t keys.
            z = node.pointers[i + 1] # z is the child that follows k.
            if len(z.keys) >= self.t:
                succ = z.keys[0]
                self.deleteKey(succ)
                node.keys[i] = succ
            else: # Case 1c: both y and z have only t - 1 keys.
                self.__mergeNodes(y, z, node, I)
                self.__checkAndMerge(node, pth[:-1])
                self.deleteKey(k)
                if self.root.keys == []: self.root = self.root.pointers[0]
        return
    
    if node == self.root and node.pointers == []:
        """Case 2: (not included in original specification): if this BTree
        only has a root left and want to delete a key from root."""
        node.isLeaf = True
        node.keys.remove(k)
        return

    if len(node.keys) >= self.t:
        """Case 3: If node is a leaf, and removing a key does not cause 
        the node having too few keys."""
        node.keys.remove(k)
        return
    
    i = bisect.bisect_left(pth[-1].keys, node.keys[0])
    leftSibling, rightSibling = self.getSiblings(node, pth[-1], i)
    nKeysLeft = len(leftSibling.keys) if leftSibling != None else 0
    nKeysRight = len(rightSibling.keys) if rightSibling != None else 0

    if nKeysLeft <= self.t - 1 and nKeysRight <= self.t - 1:
        """Case 4a, both siblings have # of keys either 0 or t - 1.
        Merge the siblings with a key up level. As this may result in 
        parent node having keys less than t - 1, therefore merge parents
        if necessary. """
        #print("pth[-2].keys ", pth[-2].keys)
        self.__mergeWithSibling(node, leftSibling, rightSibling, pth, i)
        self.__checkAndMerge(pth[-1], pth[:-1])
        self.deleteKey(k)
        
        if self.root.keys == []:
            self.root = self.root.pointers[0]
        return
    
    """Case 4b: One of the siblings of the node to be deleted have more 
        than t - 1 keys that can be "borrowed". """
    print("Running case 3a.")
    if nKeysLeft > self.t - 1: 
        # Then borrow one key from the left sibling to delete.
        node.keys.remove(k)
        node.keys.insert(0, pth[-1].keys[-1])
        pth[-1].keys.pop()
        pth[-1].keys.insert(0, leftSibling.keys[-1])
        leftSibling.keys.pop()
    else: # Borrow one key from the right sibling to delete.
        node.keys.remove(k)
        node.keys.append(pth[-1].keys[0])
        pth[-1].keys.pop(0)
        pth[-1].keys.insert(0, rightSibling.keys[0])
        rightSibling.keys.pop(0)
```

As for the stuff in the original book, the descriptions of cases 1 - 3 are correct (although I should say they've been written in a very confusing manner, one reason could be in a BTree you can't really here use the word "parent" of a node, since you don't store parent pointer at all to save memory, but I just borrow the word "parent" to describe sth. that links to a child node to be operated on). Plus, fig 18.8 d), I should say, is totally wrong and confusing because in that case deleting "D" as a key of a leaf node does not affect the validity of that node nor that BTree presented in chapter 18.1. Other parts describing BTree makes sense. Below attached my other subroutines of this BTree for reference:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Feb 13 17:13:00 2021
@author: Sam_Yan
"""

import bisect

class BTNode:
    
    def __init__(self, keys=None, pointers=None, isLeaf=True):
        self.keys = keys or []
        self.pointers = pointers or []
        self.isLeaf = isLeaf
        
    def __str__(self):
        return ("keys: " + str(self.keys) + "\n")
        

class BTree:
    
    def __init__(self, t=2):
        """t is the degree (# of keys a node contains), ranges between t
        and 2t - 1 (both sides included). When t = 2 is a 2-3-4 tree."""
        assert (t >= 2 and t == int(t)), "t value of a B-Tree should be >= 2!"
        newNode = BTNode()
        self.t = t
        self.treeStr = ""
        self.root = newNode
        
    def insertNonFull(self, node, k): 
        if node.isLeaf:
            bisect.insort(node.keys, k)
            return
        
        i = bisect.bisect(node.keys, k)
        if len(node.pointers[i].keys) == 2 * self.t - 1:
            self.splitChild(node, i)
            if k > node.keys[i]: i += 1 # Determine which subtree to go to.
        
        self.insertNonFull(node.pointers[i], k)

    def insert(self, k):
        r = self.root
        if len(self.root.keys) == 2 * self.t - 1:
            s = BTNode(isLeaf=False)
            self.root = s
            s.pointers.append(r)
            self.splitChild(s, 0)
            self.insertNonFull(s, k)
        else:
            self.insertNonFull(r, k)
    
    def splitChild(self, node, i):
        y = node.pointers[i]
        z = BTNode(isLeaf=y.isLeaf)
        z.keys = y.keys[self.t:]
        
        if not y.isLeaf: # copy pointers if y is not a leaf:
            z.pointers = y.pointers[self.t:]
                
        node.pointers.insert(i + 1, z)
        node.keys.insert(i, y.keys[self.t-1])
        del y.keys[self.t-1:]
        del y.pointers[self.t:]
 
    def __printHelper(self, r=None, level=0):
        r = r or self.root
        if r != self.root:
            self.treeStr += (" " * level + "L-" + str(level) + "-" + str(r)) 
        for node in r.pointers:            
            self.__printHelper(node, level + 1)
            
    def __delHelper(self, node=None):
        if node.isLeaf:
            del node.pointers
            del node.keys
            del node
            return
        
        for c in node.pointers:
            self.__delHelper(c)
        del node.keys
        del node.pointers
    
    def __del__(self): # Destruct this BTree.
        self.__delHelper(self.root)
    
    def __str__(self):
        # Method to obtain string info about this BTree.
        self.treeStr = "Root: " + str(self.root)
        self.__printHelper()
        return self.treeStr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Testing samples:
    t1 = BTree(t=2)
    for i in range(28):
        t1.insert(i)
    print(t1)
    print(t1.search(27)[0])

    t2 = BTree(t=3)
    alphas = "AGDJKNCMEORPSXYZTUV"
    alphas = [ch for ch in alphas]

    for ch in alphas:
        t2.insert(ch)
    #print(t2)
    t2.insert('B')
    #print(t2)
    t2.insert('Q')
    #print(t2)
    t2.insert('L')
    #print(t2)
    t2.insert('F')
    #print(t2)
    t2.deleteKey('F')   
    print(t2)
    t2.deleteKey('M')
    print(t2)
    t2.deleteKey('G')
    print(t2)
    t2.deleteKey('B')
    print(t2)
    t2.deleteKey('Z')
    print(t2)
    t2.deleteKey('D')
    print(t2)
    
    """
    t3 = BTree(t=2)
    #for ch in ['F', 'S', 'Q', 'K', 'C', 'L', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'M',
    #           'R', 'N', 'P', 'A', 'B', 'X', 'Y', 'D', 'Z', 'E']:
    for ch in ['F', 'S', 'Q', 'K', 'C', 'L', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'M']:
        t2.insert(ch)
    print(t2)    
    """
```

Hope this one helps and I sincerely look for simpler versions of this implementation or pointing out potential bugs or issues (as from my side testing on these codes for deleting, inserting and searching for keys in a BTree make sense).